# How to encrypt string using private key with openssl library?

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I have a private key in file private_key.pm and I want to encrypt this with RSA algorithm with openssl. Key length = 2048. 
Also I need to compute MD5 from encrypted result. 
I wrote this, but I am not sure if it works correctly

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE*   f;
    RSA* pRSAPRI = RSA_new();
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    RSA *private_key  =  PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(f, &pRSAPRI, NULL, NULL);

    unsigned char sourceText[100];
    unsigned char cipher[2048];
    strcpy((char*)sourceText, "some_val");
    int ret = RSA_private_encrypt(25, sourceText, cipher, private_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("RSA_private_encrypt failed\n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    std::cout << " cipher = " << cipher << std::endl;

    unsigned char md5Result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    MD5((unsigned char*)&cipher, 2048, (unsigned char*)&md5Result);

    char mdString[33];

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)md5Result[i]);

    printf("  md5 : %s\n", mdString);
    return 0;
}
```

What length of array with chars cipher has to be ? Is cipher[2048] correct ? Did I pass correctly the second argument in function PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey ?

Comment: From the manpage: `RSA_private_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding) signs the flen bytes at from (usually a message digest with an algorithm identifier) using the private key rsa and stores the signature in to. to must point to RSA_size(rsa) bytes of memory. `. Anything unclear here?

Comment: I am not sure if you are aware, that this is not really an encryption operation, but merely a signature

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I understood this. But I still need to use exactly this function. Is the rest part of code was written correctly ?

Comment: You should not be using `RSA_private_encrypt` and friends. You should be using the EVP interfaces, instead. Also see [EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @Vcvv: any solution now?